# cannot install globally @angular/cli with node.js from Red Hat software collection

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, npm, redhat

I have installed node.js 8 from Red Hat Software Collection (rh-nodejs8). Now I cannot install TypeScript or @Angular/CLI globally because access is enabled with scl-utils in my (standard user) bash session and global install requires admin rights. Is there any method to install needed tools globally in such restricted environment?

Comment: Did you try `sudo npm install -g @angular/cli` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to change npm global package installation path by trying second option of [NPM Doc for EACCESS error](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions).

Another way is to use [NPM LINK](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link) , by using link you can install and link and use npm package as a global installation.

Refer to the links for more options and brief descriptions.

Happy Coding!